# How to handle error in the calling method

Tags: c#, oop, error-handling

I don't have much experience with programming in a good `OO` way but I want to learn and today occurs a situation where I think I can improve my skills on error handling if I'm correct on my observations.

I have an event which code is logically separated in two parts :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs = AppConfigService.All().Where(a => (a.IsActive == true) && (a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages")).ToList();
    string ImageNameFilter = txtCode.Text;

    if (!ucFileExplorer.IsSavedImage(AppConfigs, ImageNameFilter))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
        return;
    }

    if (Save())
    {
        LoadForm<Materials>();
    }
}
```

The second part is just calling the `Save()` method, but my question is about the first one. There I call a method which should copy an image selected with a `OpenFileDialog` and the whole logic is in my user control that I make for file browsing cause I use it in many forms. The method that actually do the coping is this:

```
public bool IsSavedImage(IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs, string ImageNameFilter)
{
    bool IsCopied = false;
    try
    {
        string imgPath = AppConfigs[0].ConfigValue.ToString();
        File.Copy(selectedFile, imgPath + "\\" + ImageNameFilter + slectedFileName + ".jpeg");
        IsCopied = true;
    }
    catch (IOException copyError)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error saving image!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return IsCopied;
}
```

And here start my questions. I think I need the `try-catch` clause here, because this is where the actual execution takes place and makes it easier to return correct status (true or false). But I think the actual `copyError` should be handled in the calling method (my btn Click event in this case). So I have two questions, what is the right way to handle this exception, and if I want to pass it to the place where the method is called how can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to do in case of an exception? Handle it in what way? As a good practice you should handle exceptions in the BusinessLogic not on the UI level since the BusinessLogic is used from multiple places...

Comment: I want to log it and maybe remove the `messageBox` with the error message from the actual method but rather show it in my event. I'm just not sure if this is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: If you Need to handle the error in the btnSave_Click function then handle it there, but are you sure you need to? Why not just log it in the IsSavedImage function? On a side note, is that first line in btnSave_Click not possible to have some NullReferenceExceptions sometimes?

Comment: Not sure about `NullReferenceException` I haven't payed much attention to error handling at all till soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not show an error message dialog in the save function. Rename it to "SaveImage" with void return type and let the exception raise. No "if" in the caller but a try-catch block that shows the error message dialog in case an exception happened.

Comment: Yes, It is a perfectly vaild approach, to let the exception bubble up. Alternatively, you could catch the exceptions and throw your own custom exceptions. This allows you to clean up, to re-group different exceptions, to provide additional information to the caller, etc.

Comment: All good answers but I think I'm gonna use your approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can define a event in the user-control and fire it whenver you get a exception

 and then subscribe to this exception event from the main parent and handle it accordingly.

Something like this.

```
public Action<Exception> OnExceptionInUserControl;
public bool IsSavedImage(IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs, string ImageNameFilter)
{
    bool IsCopied = false;
    try
    {
        string imgPath = AppConfigs[0].ConfigValue.ToString();
        File.Copy(selectedFile, imgPath + "\\" + ImageNameFilter + slectedFileName + ".jpeg");
        IsCopied = true;
    }
    catch (IOException copyError)
    {
        OnExceptionInUserControl(copyError);
        return false;
    }
    return IsCopied;
}
```

in the mainWindow

```
userControl.OnExceptionInUserControl += new Action<Exception>(ExceptionEventHandler);
```

Comment: It looks a bit overkill, but on the other hand it lets you separate nicely the logic for error handling...

Comment: One should follow the conventions for event handlers for something like this. I think it is important that code should follow a similar pattern in structure and naming as the base library.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I agree. More generally, a good design sticks to one kind of error handling techinique. If you use exceptions, stay with exceptions. If you have events handlers/callbacks to handle error cases elsewhere, use them (and catch third-party exception and transform them, to show a consistent behaviour)

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I like code that follow a similar pattern to the BCL too. However, this is a case where different parts of the library use different techniques (event handlers vs. exceptions)

Comment: @dema80 I think it is okay for the `IsSavedImage` method to have exception handling via a `try-catch` block in it. That doesn't break the pattern. UI event handling code should follow the pattern though. UI event handlers should never throw exceptions because there is no way to put try-catches around them. In general any exceptions generated within an event handler attached to an event of a UI component should be caught and handled within that event handler. Once caught, they should IMHO be surfaced via an error event, which can then be handled normally.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I agree

Answer (score 2):

> what is the right way to handle this exception

It really depends on your application; in general, you handle the exception where you need (or can!) handle it. For example, in the place where you can collect more information, and/or react to the error (display an error message, log, retry...)

> and if I want to pass it to the place where the method is called how can I do it?

You just handle the exception at an higher level: exceptions are handy because they are propagated to the caller until someone catches them. Just insert the `try... catch` block in the calling function(s) (be careful to consider all the executions paths, or exceptions that will not find any function handling them will be uncaught, terminating the program).

Generally speaking, I remember four main ways of handling errors in an application: return values (error codes or booleans), exceptions, `GetLastError`-style (store an error code somewhere, have the programmer call a function to retrieve it), callbacks (provide a function to be called in case of error).

For a while, exceptions where said to be THE OO way of handling error. But you now have also event handlers (a special case of callbacks, after all) in well designed frameworks.

In general, a good design should choose one and stick to that, eventually "transforming" one error type to the other (for example, catching exception from thrid-party code and making them into a callback, as in Umar Farooq Khawaja answer)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with dutzu that the actual error checking should be done in the business layer. Further to that, I would suggest that your UI component or form should expose an ErrorHandler event which you should raise whenever there is an error condition.

This way, if there is an error handler attached to the error event handler, that will be called and that error handler can take the appropriate action, if need be.

You can define an `ErrorEventHandler` delegate such as:

```
public void ErrorEventHandler(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e);
```

And an `ErrorEventArgs` class such as:

```
public class ErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // error info exposed via readonly properties
}
```

You can create an error event in your UI component/form like so:

```
public class UIForm
{
    public event ErrorEventHandler ErrorOccurred;

    protected void RaiseErrorEvent(ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorEventHandler eh = ErrorOccurred;

        if (eh != null)
        {
            eh.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs = AppConfigService.All().Where(a => (a.IsActive == true) && (a.ConfigProperty == "MaterialImages")).ToList();
        string ImageNameFilter = txtCode.Text;

        try
        {
            if (!ucFileExplorer.IsSavedImage(AppConfigs, ImageNameFilter))
            {
                RaiseErrorEvent(new ErrorEventArgs());
                return;
            }

            if (Save())
            {
                LoadForm<Materials>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // convert exception to an ErrorEventArgs e here
            RaiseErrorEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ucFileExplorer.IsSavedImage` should not show any UI or throw up any message boxes. It should return only `true` or `false`. Alternatively, it can throw an exception which can be caught in the `btnSave_Click`, which can then be surfaced via `RaiseErrorEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't catch the exception this way, as this is currently not consistent: your method catches only `IOException` exceptions, so it might throw other exceptions that won't ever be caught (not caught in `IsSavedImage` nor in calling method), such as `UnauthorizedAccessException` for instance.

The other issue I see is that you always display a message box in case of `IOException` exception. I would remove this part, as one day you might want to handle exceptions in different ways, and you don't want to change how it is currently handled in a core/business function.

For instance something like:

```
public bool SaveImage(IList<AppConfig> AppConfigs, string ImageNameFilter)
{
    string imgPath = AppConfigs[0].ConfigValue.ToString();
    File.Copy(selectedFile, imgPath + "\\" + ImageNameFilter + slectedFileName + ".jpeg");
}

...

try
{
    xxx.SaveImage(....);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    // Message to user that the access is denied?
    ...
}
catch (any exception you can handle properly)
{

}
catch
{
    // Couln't be handled properly, so displays generic error message
    ...
}
```